# How do i copy a directory with SSL information into kafka-ui docker image

Tags: docker, ssl, apache-kafka, jks

I've got the following configuration:

```
  ssl-kafka-ui:
    image: provectuslabs/kafka-ui
    container_name: ssl-webui
    logging:
      driver: "json-file"
      options:
        max-size: "2048m"
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    volumes:
      - ./ssl/:/var/private/ssl
    restart: always
    depends_on: 
      - ssl-broker-one
      - ssl-zookeeper
    environment:
      - KAFKA_CLUSTERS_0_NAME=local
      - KAFKA_CLUSTERS_0_BOOTSTRAPSERVERS=bud48:9092
      - KAFKA_CLUSTERS_0_ZOOKEEPER=ssl-zookeeper=2181
      - KAFKA_CLUSTERS_0_PROPERTIES_SECURITY_PROTOCOL=SSL
      - KAFKA_CLUSTERS_0_PROPERTIES_SSL_KEYSTORE_LOCATION=/var/private/ssl/kafka.server.keystore.jks
      - KAFKA_CLUSTERS_0_PROPERTIES_SSL_KEYSTORE_PASSWORD=MyServerPassword123
      - KAFKA_CLUSTERS_0_PROPERTIES_SSL_KEYSTORE_TYPE=JKS
      - KAFKA_CLUSTERS_0_PROPERTIES_SSL_TRUSTSTORE_LOCATION=/var/private/ssl/kafka.server.truststore.jks
      - KAFKA_CLUSTERS_0_PROPERTIES_SSL_TRUSTSTORE_PASSWORD=MyServerPassword123
      - KAFKA_CLUSTERS_0_PROPERTIES_SSL_TRUSTSTORE_TYPE=JKS
```

however when I run it, the docker-container can't find that directory containing the keys

```
ssl-webui                   | java.lang.IllegalStateException: Error while creating AdminClient for Cluster local
ssl-webui                   |   at com.provectus.kafka.ui.service.AdminClientServiceImpl.lambda$createAdminClient$3(AdminClientServiceImpl.java:45)
ssl-webui                   |   at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.lambda$onErrorMap$31(Mono.java:3733)
ssl-webui                   |   at reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnErrorResume$ResumeSubscriber.onError(FluxOnErrorResume.java:94)
ssl-webui                   |   at reactor.core.publisher.Operators.error(Operators.java:198)
ssl-webui                   |   at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFlatMap.trySubscribeScalarMap(FluxFlatMap.java:135)
ssl-webui                   |   at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap.subscribeOrReturn(MonoFlatMap.java:53)
ssl-webui                   |   at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:4385)
ssl-webui                   |   at reactor.core.publisher.FluxSwitchIfEmpty$SwitchIfEmptySubscriber.onComplete(FluxSwitchIfEmpty.java:82)
ssl-webui                   |   at reactor.core.publisher.Operators.complete(Operators.java:137)
ssl-webui                   |   at reactor.core.publisher.MonoEmpty.subscribe(MonoEmpty.java:46)
ssl-webui                   |   at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:4400)
ssl-webui                   |   at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onNext(FluxFlatMap.java:426)
ssl-webui                   |   at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPublishOn$PublishOnSubscriber.runAsync(FluxPublishOn.java:440)
ssl-webui                   |   at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPublishOn$PublishOnSubscriber.run(FluxPublishOn.java:527)
ssl-webui                   |   at reactor.core.scheduler.WorkerTask.call(WorkerTask.java:84)
ssl-webui                   |   at reactor.core.scheduler.WorkerTask.call(WorkerTask.java:37)
ssl-webui                   |   at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
ssl-webui                   |   at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:304)
ssl-webui                   |   at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
ssl-webui                   |   at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
ssl-webui                   |   at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:830)
ssl-webui                   | Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.KafkaException: Failed to create new KafkaAdminClient
ssl-webui                   |   at org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.KafkaAdminClient.createInternal(KafkaAdminClient.java:540)
ssl-webui                   |   at org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.Admin.create(Admin.java:134)
ssl-webui                   |   at org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.AdminClient.create(AdminClient.java:39)
ssl-webui                   |   at com.provectus.kafka.ui.service.AdminClientServiceImpl.lambda$createAdminClient$2(AdminClientServiceImpl.java:41)
ssl-webui                   |   at reactor.core.publisher.MonoSupplier.call(MonoSupplier.java:86)
ssl-webui                   |   at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFlatMap.trySubscribeScalarMap(FluxFlatMap.java:127)
ssl-webui                   |   ... 16 common frames omitted
ssl-webui                   | Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.KafkaException: Failed to load SSL keystore /var/private/ssl/kafka.server.keystore.jks of type JKS
ssl-webui                   |   at org.apache.kafka.common.security.ssl.DefaultSslEngineFactory$FileBasedStore.load(DefaultSslEngineFactory.java:377)
ssl-webui                   |   at org.apache.kafka.common.security.ssl.DefaultSslEngineFactory$FileBasedStore.<init>(DefaultSslEngineFactory.java:349)
ssl-webui                   |   at org.apache.kafka.common.security.ssl.DefaultSslEngineFactory.createKeystore(DefaultSslEngineFactory.java:299)
ssl-webui                   |   at org.apache.kafka.common.security.ssl.DefaultSslEngineFactory.configure(DefaultSslEngineFactory.java:161)
ssl-webui                   |   at org.apache.kafka.common.security.ssl.SslFactory.instantiateSslEngineFactory(SslFactory.java:138)
ssl-webui                   |   at org.apache.kafka.common.security.ssl.SslFactory.configure(SslFactory.java:95)
ssl-webui                   |   at org.apache.kafka.common.network.SslChannelBuilder.configure(SslChannelBuilder.java:74)
ssl-webui                   |   at org.apache.kafka.common.network.ChannelBuilders.create(ChannelBuilders.java:192)
ssl-webui                   |   at org.apache.kafka.common.network.ChannelBuilders.clientChannelBuilder(ChannelBuilders.java:81)
ssl-webui                   |   at org.apache.kafka.clients.ClientUtils.createChannelBuilder(ClientUtils.java:105)
ssl-webui                   |   at org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.KafkaAdminClient.createInternal(KafkaAdminClient.java:513)
ssl-webui                   |   ... 21 common frames omitted
ssl-webui                   | Caused by: java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException: /var/private/ssl/kafka.server.keystore.jks
ssl-webui                   |   at java.base/sun.nio.fs.UnixException.translateToIOException(UnixException.java:90)
ssl-webui                   |   at java.base/sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:111)
ssl-webui                   |   at java.base/sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:116)
ssl-webui                   |   at java.base/sun.nio.fs.UnixFileSystemProvider.newByteChannel(UnixFileSystemProvider.java:219)
ssl-webui                   |   at java.base/java.nio.file.Files.newByteChannel(Files.java:374)
ssl-webui                   |   at java.base/java.nio.file.Files.newByteChannel(Files.java:425)
ssl-webui                   |   at java.base/java.nio.file.spi.FileSystemProvider.newInputStream(FileSystemProvider.java:420)
ssl-webui                   |   at java.base/java.nio.file.Files.newInputStream(Files.java:159)
ssl-webui                   |   at org.apache.kafka.common.security.ssl.DefaultSslEngineFactory$FileBasedStore.load(DefaultSslEngineFactory.java:370)
```

I have also tried going into the container to confirm, but it locks up as soon as I enter a command (see below). bash shell doesn't work either.

```
docker exec -t ssl-webui /bin/sh
```

Is there any other way to get the ssl information into the container, or find a default location that is accessible?

Comment: What file permissions are on the keys? And I think you're looking for `docker exec -ti` if you want an _interactive_ shell

Comment: cheers that did solve that issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding this to the docker-compose.yml

```
    user: "0:0"
```

solved the permissions issue